# should articles be used after conjunction?

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

```
He is an amateur and/or/but a hobbyist photographer.
```

or

```
He is an amateur and/or/but hobbyist photographer.
```

I'm asking this as different articles are used before **amateur** and **hobbyist**.

Does it depend on the conjunction?

Comment: Can you think of a different example? I don't think I'd use either here, as the collocations 'amateur photographer' and 'hobbyist photographer' are probably too cohesive to ellipt.

Comment: 'He is an officer and a gentleman' is almost set in stone. 'He is a husband and father' doesn't sound unusual.

Comment: After [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy)), sure. After opposition, no.

Answer (score 2):

As Edwin Ashworth points out in his comment, an article can be used, but it does not always appear.

Looking at the two examples he gives:

> He is an officer and a gentleman.

This describes two fully independent and separate concepts, both of which apply to the subject.

> He is a husband and father.

If the sentence stands alone, one could also say "a father". However, here we describe two *roles* the person plays, and the sentence could easily be extended to:

> He is a husband and father to his loved ones.

The difference lies in how we parse these sentences:

> He is [an officer] and (he is) [a gentleman].
>   He is a [husband and father] to his loved ones.

Now, in the original sentence, something else plays up: both words are adjectives to *photographer*. To avoid the semantic confusion of the synonyms *amateur* and *professional*, let's replace them with *professional* and *terrible*.

> He is a professional but a terrible photographer.
>   He is [a professional] but (he is) [a terrible photographer].

This could mean he is a professional journalist, but he should not make his own pictures.

> He is a professional but terrible photographer.
>   He is a [professional but terrible] photographer.

So he is a professional photographer, but we do not expect he will make a big career out of it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more usual to leave out the article.

However, we can bring more into what is conjoined if we want:

> He is an amateur and a hobbyist photographer.
>
> He is an amateur photographer and a hobbyist photographer.

The restating adds emphasis. The second example that repeats the entire clause adds a lot of emphasis, so we would only use it if we wanted to deeply underline the point.

This is a specific case of something general to conjunctions; we normally omit repetition, but can include it for effect.